# Как отправлять видео в бот с серверов телеграма?

Tags: c#, telegram-bot, telegram, telebot

Хочу через file id отправлять юзеру видео, уже загруженное в телеграм, чтобы оно не грузилось каждый раз заново. Нашёл похожий вопрос, но что-то не особо получается повторить. Пишу вот такой код:

```
if (message.Text.ToLower() == "видео")
{
  await botClient.SendVideoAsync(
  chatId: message.Chat.Id,
  video: message.Video.FileId = "https://t.me/c/1652849086/242");
}
```

То есть я передаю ссылку на сообщение с видео, чтобы FileId достал id этого видео. Это вообще так должно работать?

Comment: А что, не работает?

Comment: System.NullReferenceException :(
Я подумал что это из-за того что ссылка на приватный канал. Но когда сделал ссылку на публичный - то же самое

Comment: _Вопросы с просьбами помочь с отладкой («почему этот код не работает?») должны включать желаемое поведение, конкретную проблему или ошибку и минимальный код для её воспроизведения прямо в вопросе._

Answer (score 1):

**Способ работы с публичными каналами/группами:**

Сперва, я опишу способ получения [ссылки на видео](https://cdn4.telegram-cdn.org/file/bb5dc6638a.mp4?token=eCanQCY5VRcEZvjQoL7jLmgOPjeeAVrKKqPF7KRFGGUKA6Adae38VASsOLQbGLAl92yNmcMRK0Nhtp8NwvfDCFH6ukakBgOAEYj8OR_coxn92CeYxbapQfKRR2h3aywkZVAdlfNEreoWzeUF6hC4swjDhtSWqWoM1VQszQo_xZxrZfJlZcRMtLMdMGMz9LbdW9VrCVf4L-qYZKQbbsOB3V4qQlofzX6gTevibh-janrF9aIyXQ_2s0JIixACn2x2oPnCrY2wwB6kVMZA6ks69qhzH8Fqe2JaZuY0QpKwRZvZrJvQbzzxLAc4oHEl7oIbpgkd-oQi7ELqVBnbEGUMcg) вручную, с ней все должно работать, в дальнейшем мы ее извлечем программно

1. идем в тот канал где опубликовано видео
2. находим видео
3. кликаем на сообщение и копируем `ссылку на сообщение/message link`
4. вставляем адресную строку браузера
5. открываем девтулзы <kbd>F12</kbd>
6. переходим на вкладку `Сеть/Network`
7. запускаем видео
8. изучаем `GET` запрос
9. теперь у нас реальная ссылка на видео

Ссылку можно было найти в исходниках на странице, но в данном случае это не так важно, это просто для понимания того, что **ссылка на видео - это не ссылка на пост**.

Выглядит она так:

```
https://cdn4.telegram-cdn.org/file/bb5dc6638a.mp4?token=eCanQCY5VRcEZvjQoL7jLmgOPjeeAVrKKqPF7KRFGGUKA6Adae38VASsOLQbGLAl92yNmcMRK0Nhtp8NwvfDCFH6ukakBgOAEYj8OR_coxn92CeYxbapQfKRR2h3aywkZVAdlfNEreoWzeUF6hC4swjDhtSWqWoM1VQszQo_xZxrZfJlZcRMtLMdMGMz9LbdW9VrCVf4L-qYZKQbbsOB3V4qQlofzX6gTevibh-janrF9aIyXQ_2s0JIixACn2x2oPnCrY2wwB6kVMZA6ks69qhzH8Fqe2JaZuY0QpKwRZvZrJvQbzzxLAc4oHEl7oIbpgkd-oQi7ELqVBnbEGUMcg
```

**Теперь о самом интересном:**

1. нам нужно скачать веб страницу поста: `url_группы/id_поста`

В `C#` это выглядит примерно так:

```
var url = "url_группы/id_поста";
WebRequest request = HttpWebRequest.Create(url);  
WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();  
StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream());  
string responseText = reader.ReadToEnd();  
Response.Write(responseText);
```

2. извлечь информацию `src` из тега `video`

```html
  <video src="https://cdn4.telegram-cdn.org/file/bb5dc6638a.mp4?token=eCanQCY5VRcEZvjQoL7jLmgOPjeeAVrKKqPF7KRFGGUKA6Adae38VASsOLQbGLAl92yNmcMRK0Nhtp8NwvfDCFH6ukakBgOAEYj8OR_coxn92CeYxbapQfKRR2h3aywkZVAdlfNEreoWzeUF6hC4swjDhtSWqWoM1VQszQo_xZxrZfJlZcRMtLMdMGMz9LbdW9VrCVf4L-qYZKQbbsOB3V4qQlofzX6gTevibh-janrF9aIyXQ_2s0JIixACn2x2oPnCrY2wwB6kVMZA6ks69qhzH8Fqe2JaZuY0QpKwRZvZrJvQbzzxLAc4oHEl7oIbpgkd-oQi7ELqVBnbEGUMcg" class="tgme_widget_message_video js-message_video" width="100%" height="100%"></video>
```

Код примерно такой:

```
string url = Regex.Match(responseText, "<video[^>]+src=\"([^\"]+)",
    RegexOptions.IgnoreCase).Groups[1].Value;
```

3. можно вставлять в комманду бота (изучив дополнительно документацию)

**Мои предположения:**

1. Не хватит прав для скачивания страницы (CORS)
2. Телеграм все равно скачает видео,

В этом случае делиться нужно не видео, а сообщением `messages.forwardMessages` (по документации)

Answer (score 0):

Оказывается `FileId` - это не что-то в виде ссылки. `FileId` выглядит так:

```
"BAACAgIAAxkBAAIBEGMOZzOq544k7MthGRqDSqrWk1stAALiHQACGa0oSXt2bCR6FxVbKQQ"
```

Узнать `FileId` можно, если залогировать `message?.Video?.FileId` и отправить боту сообщение с видео.

---

Осталось только узнать, как не вручную узнать `FileId` у кучи видео сразу, но это уже другой вопрос.

Answer (score 0):

Для начала вам нужно получить расширенную информацию о видео

```
var file = await botClient.GetFileAsync(update.Message.Video.FileId);
```

После чего вы сможете его отправить, указав его id

```
await botClient.SendVideoAsync(
chatId: message.Chat.Id,
video: file.FileId);
```